# Discord.js : How do i make my bot play an audio when someones enter any channel

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I found someone's trying the same but mine appers this " TypeError: oldPresence.guild.channels.get is not a function"

```
bot.on('voiceStateUpdate', (oldPresence, newPresence) => {
let newUserChannel = newPresence.voiceChannel
let oldUserChannel = oldPresence.voiceChannel
let textChannel = oldPresence.guild.channels.get('TEXTCHANNEL ID')
connection.join()
.then()
if(oldUserChannel === undefined && newUserChannel !== undefined) {

  if (newMember.id === 'MEMBER ID')         
  {   
     newUserChannel.join()
     .then(connection => {
        console.log("Joined voice channel!");
        const dispatcher = connection.playFile("E:\UniConverter\Downloaded\Trio.mp3");

        dispatcher.on("end", end => {newUserChannel.leave()});
     })
      .catch(console.error);

  }
         else                                      
           textChannel.send("Hello") 
         } 
}
```

);

bot.login (token);

Answer (score 0):

In the latest version of Discord.js (v12) the [correct function](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildChannelManager?scrollTo=cache) is:

```js
oldPresence.guild.channels.cache.get('ID');
```

Comment: Thanks bro you save-me but it didnt work at all , could you help with this error too ? lol                                    Appers that connection is not defined , how do i define the connection                                                ReferenceError: connection is not defined